# Rails and RSpec: Testing controllers with the same name in different namespace (module)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, ruby-2.2

I have rails 4.1.16 API application that is tested using RSpec 3.4.0, and I experience problems with testing classes called the same name in a different module.

The structure is:

```
app/controllers/bar/notifications_controller.rb

class Bar::NotificationsController < ApiController
  ...
end
```

and controller with the same name in a different module:

```
app/controllers/foo/bar/notifications_controller.rb

module Foo
  class Bar::NotificationsController < ApiController
    ...
  end
end
```

The `Foo` is a new module and does not have tests yet.
After adding it, all the corresponding controller tests for the old `Bar::NotificationsController` started to fail.

The spec file:

```
spec/controllers/bar/notifications_controller_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe Bar::NotificationsController, type: :controller do
  ...
end
```

All the tests in that spec file fail with the same error:

```
RuntimeError:
   @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
```

The problem does not exist when I change the controller name in the `Foo` module:

```
app/controllers/foo/bar/foo_notifications_controller.rb

module Foo
  class Bar::FooNotificationsController < ApiController
    ...
  end
end
```

I already tried adding on top of the spec file `require 'bar/notifications_controller'` and using the class name as a string `describe "Bar::NotificationsController, type: :controller` but it did not solve the issue (the same error).

Why is this happening? What is the solution?

I want to believe there is a tiny thing I did not try yet and I don't have to pollute my code and the structure with nonsense names just to make the specs pass.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you try defining the namespaces using `module Bar` instead of defining in the class name itself?

Comment: Try `describe ::Bar::NotificationsController, type: :controller do`

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I've take to including *all* namespacing in the class definition. Something like:

```
app/controllers/foo/bar/notifications_controller.rb

class Foo::Bar::NotificationsController < ApiController
  ...
end
```

While, at first glance, this might look the same as:

```
app/controllers/foo/bar/notifications_controller.rb

module Foo
  class Bar::NotificationsController < ApiController
    ...
  end
end
```

These are, in fact, different. The difference is in how Rails handles autoloading of constants. I won't go into the details here because it's a longer topic and there are good articles/posts out in the web-o-sphere.

You can find good articles on how Rails handles autoloading like [this one](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/) (or try Googling `rails constant loading`)

Also, as the article notes, Ruby constant loading operates differently than Rails loading. Good information on Ruby constant loading can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/kyrylo/6413067) (or try Googling `ruby constant loading`).

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Could you explain shortly why does it happen? Or some resource on the topic? I would expect modules and classes written both ways to behave the same way as they are the same thing :|