# LoadError: Unable to autoload constant with dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can somebody help me to resolve this?

> LoadError: Unable to autoload constant BankAccounts::ValidateNewTransaction, expected /home/amd/bank/app/operations/bank_accounts/validate_new_transaction.rb to define it

Even with `require_dependency` it is not working.

Comment: How about you post the `BankAccounts::ValidateNewTransaction` code? And, verify that it's in the correct location. And, stop your server, run `spring stop`, and restart your server.

Comment: this is my code

Answer (score 5):

As a wild guess, do you define your class like this:

```
  module BankAccounts
    class ValidateNewTransaction

      ...

    end
  end
```

If so, you might want to try:

```
  class BankAccounts::ValidateNewTransaction

    ...

  end
```

That helped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461535/rails-and-rspec-testing-controllers-with-the-same-name-in-different-namespace/41464044#41464044).

Also, in your comment, you wrote:

```
  module BankAccounts 
    class ValidateNewtransaction 
      def initialize(amount:, transaction_type:, bank_account_id:) end
```

Is that from your actual code? Because, you have `ValidateNewtransaction`, not `ValidateNewTransaction` (the `T` needs to be upper case).

Comment: module BankAccounts
  class ValidateNewtransaction
    def initialize(amount:, transaction_type:, bank_account_id:)
      
   end

Comment: Please don't add code in comments. You can add it to your original question. It's too hard to look at in comments.

Comment: Did you try the class declaration all on one line? Making sure spring isn't running?

Comment: oh sorry !  you right about the t it wasnt upper i just see the mistake !

Comment: Super, glad to help. Please feel free to accept the answer if you see fit.

Comment: i have an another error NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
 from app/operations/bank_accounts/validate_new_transaction.rb:31:in `validate_existence_of_account!'

Comment: def validate_existence_of_account!
      if @bank_account.blank?
        @errors << "Account not found"
      end
    end

Comment: How about you accept this answer. Then post the new question separately and I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

This error is typically caused by not defining your classes in the correct files. Have you double-checked that `app/operations/bank_accounts/validate_new_transaction.rb` actually defines exactly that class? (`BankAccounts::ValidateNewTransaction`).

You can read some more about this at [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-algorithms), in 6.1.2 "Top Level Constants" mentions that exact error - LoadError.

Comment: NameError: uninitialized constant BankAccounts::ValidateNewtransaction
 from app/operations/bank_accounts/validate_new_transaction.rb:2:in `<module:BankAccounts>'
 from app/operations/bank_accounts/validate_new_transaction.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: Could you add the file above?

Comment: module BankAccounts
  class ValidateNewtransaction
    def initialize(amount:, transaction_type:, bank_account_id:)
      
   end

Comment: even when i add the file above he give me a error again something like this ::

Comment: i have an another error NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
 from app/operations/bank_accounts/validate_new_transaction.rb:31:in `validate_existence_of_account!'

Comment: def validate_existence_of_account!
      if @bank_account.blank?
        @errors << "Account not found"
      end

Comment: Try with ValidateNewTransaction with a capital T.

Comment: thanks for you help ! but the problem was resolved since yesterday !